# Flutter pub get error (server unavailable)

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to add a package MapBox to Flutter. The project buidings correctly but I'm getting an error when I'm trying to download packages:

flutter run

```
OS Error: The remote computer refused the network connection.
, errno = 1225, address = storage.googleapis.com, port = 63216
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...
OS Error: The remote computer refused the network connection.
, errno = 1225, address = storage.googleapis.com, port = 63430
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...
OS Error: The remote computer refused the network connection.
, errno = 1225, address = storage.googleapis.com, port = 63650
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 3 in 4 seconds...
OS Error: The remote computer refused the network connection.
, errno = 1225, address = storage.googleapis.com, port = 63901
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 4 in 8 seconds...
OS Error: The remote computer refused the network connection.
, errno = 1225, address = storage.googleapis.com, port = 64203
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 5 in 16 seconds...
```

I'm tried to use **flutter doctor -v**, but it doesn't show errors (**No issues found**).

I'm checked the internet connection, but didn't find problem in this. Also I deleted Antivirus, but it doesn't help. I can to connect to pub.dev from browser and download any package. But I can't connect from Android Studio. What's problem? How can I fix it?

I'm using an Adroid Studio 2020.3.1.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried to just run `flutter pub get` from command line in project's directory to eliminate issues with Android Studio itself?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work